# Batch printing Adobe Illustrator

Tags: c#, pdf, reference, adobe-illustrator

I have a task to print a batch of illustrator files.
There are 8 AI documents and 1 CSV file. In the CSV file there are info that I need to change in the AI document before printing.
Actually I am doing this by using the AI reference in Visual Studio and using doc.printOut(), my problem is that it sends 1 file per printOut() to the printer and it is not that fast, the more printers I have, the more delay to send the document between the printers.

I was wondering if I could use another library to print this or use another function from this library. Maybe even using some batch actions inside illustrator, but I guess that wouldn't change much in performance, Well, I don't know.
Was reading some threads here and saw that the AI file is nearly identical to a PDF file, maybe load the documents within a adobe PDF reference in C# would help to print faster?

Any tips please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [VBScript reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/illustrator/scripting/illustrator_scripting_reference_vbscript_cs5.pdf) for `printOut()` I'm guessing that Illustrator does a lot of work before firing off a given print job (the `PrintOptions` object is a collection of options each of which has a dozen or so different settings to twiddle... no thank you).

I suggest you `SaveAs()` your file to PDF, and print that instead.  PDFSaveOptions has a crap-load of options itself, but it looks like (almost?) all of them are optional.

Comment: would you help me printing a PDF in C#?

Comment: I actually don't know C#, VBScript, or Illustrator's APIs.  I just did a bit of searching and found that reference I linked.